# ASP.NET MVC 5 ViewModel Binding

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-viewmodel

I cant bind data (events) fetch from service in ViewModel in controller.
It works ok without ViewModel.

**Domain model**

```
namespace Tournament.Model
{
      public class Event
    {
        public int EventID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
        public string Geolocation { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }
        public string State { get; set; }
        public string Country { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string Type { get; set; }

        public virtual List<Team> Teams { get; set; }

    }
}
```

I need just few properties for:
**ViewModel**

```
    namespace Tournament.Web.ViewModel.EventViews
    {
        public class EventIndexViewModel
        {
            public int EventIndexViewModelID { get; set; }
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
            public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
            public string City { get; set; }

        }
    }
```

And now in **controller** I have this (I ommited service initializing part - that works fine). So events hold list of Events (from domain model).

```
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            //Create list of Events
            var events = eventService.GetEvents();

            //Search events

            //Add _eventService Event details to var event

            var model = new EventIndexViewModel();
            List<EventIndexViewModel> modelList = new List<EventIndexViewModel>();

            foreach (var Event in events)
            {
                events.Add(new Event {
                    Name = model.Name,
                    StartDate = model.StartDate,
                    EndDate = model.EndDate });
                    modelList.Add(model);
            }           

            return View(modelList);
        }
    }
}
```

Generated standard List view based on ViewModel and got:

```
Server Error in '/' Application.

Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.

Source Error: 


Line 36:             List<EventIndexViewModel> modelList = new List<EventIndexViewModel>();
Line 37: 
**Line 38:             foreach (var Event in events)**
Line 39:             {
Line 40:                 events.Add(new Event {
```

**UPDATE -SOLUTION: This is working controller now:**

```
 public ActionResult Index()
        {
            //Create list of Events
            var domainEvents = eventService.GetEvents();


            //Add domain Events to ViewModel Event properties

            var eventViewModel = new EventIndexViewModel();
            List<EventIndexViewModel> eventListViewModel = new List<EventIndexViewModel>();

            foreach (var domainEvent in domainEvents)
            {
                eventListViewModel.Add(new EventIndexViewModel
                {    
                    Name = domainEvent.Name,
                    StartDate = domainEvent.StartDate,
                    EndDate = domainEvent.EndDate });
                }           

            return View(eventListViewModel);
        }
```

**UPDATE 2 - SHORTER AND I GUESS BETTER WAY OF DOING IT WITH LINQ**

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {
            //Create list of Events
            var domainEvents = eventService.GetEvents();

            //Search events

            //Add domain Event list to ViewModel list

                var eventListViewModel = domainEvents.Select(
                    x => new EventIndexViewModel()
                    {
                        Name = x.Name,
                        StartDate = x.StartDate,
                        EndDate = x.EndDate,
                        City = x.City

                    })
                        .ToList();

            return View(eventListViewModel);
        }
```

Comment: You will find this far easier with a linq `.Select()` - `var eventListViewModel = domainEvents.Select(x => new EventIndexViewModel() { Name = x.Name, StartDate = x.StartDate, EndDate = x.EndDate }).ToList();`

Comment: @Stephen Muecke Great, that works nice. I'll added to solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're adding a collection to itself:

```
foreach (var Event in events)
{
    events.Add(new Event {
    //...
```

So, for every `event` you want to add an `event`?  Perhaps you meant to add elements to `modelList` instead?

```
foreach (var Event in events)
{
    modelList.Add(new EventIndexViewModel {
    //...
```

(Side note: A cleaner naming strategy will help you identify problems more easily.  `modelList` doesn't really tell you what it is.  You're probably using the `events` variable because, semantically, you should be working with events.  Maybe you can call them `domainEvents` and `viewEvents`?  Also, naming a variable `Event` which is of type `Event` is just asking for problems.)

Comment: Works! Thx! I'll put updated controller in post bellow my question. Please comment whether naming conventions looks proper now.